# Factory pattern create pre-built builders

Tags: design-patterns

I have a `SearchRequest` object that can be created using a `SearchRequestBuilder`. Some of our predefined `SearchRequestBuilder` can be quite complex. I have seen factory patterns used to create different types of the same parent object, but I was wondering if this is proper design to have something like this:

```
public class SearchRequestBuilderFactory {

    public enum Type {
        SEARCH, MATCH
    }

    public SearchRequestBuilder createBuilder(Type type) {
        switch (type) {
        case SEARCH:
            return createSearchBuilder();
            break;
        case MATCHING:
            return createMatchBuilder();
            break;
        }
    }

    private SearchRequestBuilder createSearchBuilder() {
        SearchRequestBuilder srb = new SearchRequestBuilder();
        srb.addField("*");
        srb.addFilter("searchFilter");
        return srb;
    }

    private SearchRequestBuilder createMatchBuilder() {
        SearchRequestBuilder srb = new SearchRequestBuilder();
        srb.addFilter("matchFilter");
        srb.addThreshold(0.5);
        return srb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no restriction of having a factory of builders. BUT they are uncommon for a reason...

We use Builder whenever the properties of an object are not mandatory to it's construction. I don't know if that is the case in your application. So I will try to give a proper answer that will cover all the scenarios.

SCENARIO 1: Some of the class members are only in use in a certain mode. In this case **the actual class need to be divided to different classes altogether**. In your case if the property threshold will never be part of a search request then it should not be part of a SearchRequest class, and you should have a MatchRequest class that will hold it.

SCENARIO 2: All properties are in use but in a certain mode some of them will have **constant values which we will never change externally**. In this case we use different builders (with inheritance) not a factory. This will restrict the accessibility of these properties externally which is mandatory.

SCENARIO 3: All properties are in use but in a certain mode some of them will have **predefined values which may change externally**. Here I'm recommending to use the same solution as 2 since it is more readable, maintainable and [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) than using a factory. So for example in your case lets say that the value passed to addField() needs to change to "*.*" and the value passed to addThreshold() needs to change to "1.5" than two developers can accomplish these changes without having to touch the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good approach.

Maybe you want to encapsulate the `SearchRequestBuilder`'s configuration logic in order to have

- better unit testability
- decrease cyclomatic complexity

For example:

```
interface SearchRequestBuilderConfigurer {
    public void configure(SearchRequestBuilder srb);
}

class DefaultSearchRequestBuilderConfigurer implements SearchRequestBuilderConfigurer {
    public void configure(SearchRequestBuilder srb){
        srb.addField("*");
        srb.addFilter("searchFilter");
    }
}

class MatchSearchRequestBuilderConfigurer implements SearchRequestBuilderConfigurer {
    public void configure(SearchRequestBuilder srb){
        srb.addFilter("matchFilter");
        srb.addThreshold(0.5);
    }
}
```

After you encapsulated the configuration logic you can use a map instead of switch statements.

```
public class SearchRequestBuilderFactory {

    public enum Type {
        SEARCH, MATCH
    }

    private Map<Type, SearchRequestBuilderConfigurer> type2Configurer = new HashMap<Type, SearchRequestBuilderConfigurer>();

    public SearchRequestBuilderFactory(){
        type2Configurer.put(Type.SEARCH, new DefaultSearchRequestBuilderConfigurer());
        type2Configurer.put(Type.MATCH, new MatchSearchRequestBuilderConfigurer());
    }

    public SearchRequestBuilder createBuilder(Type type) {
        SearchRequestBuilderConfigurer configurer = type2Configurer.get(type);
        if(configurer == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("type " +  type + " is not supported");
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder srb = new SearchRequestBuilder();
        configurer.configure(srb);
        return srb;
    }

    private SearchRequestBuilder createSearchBuilder() {
        SearchRequestBuilder srb = new SearchRequestBuilder();
        srb.addField("*");
        srb.addFilter("searchFilter");
        return srb;
    }

    private SearchRequestBuilder createMatchBuilder() {
        SearchRequestBuilder srb = new SearchRequestBuilder();
        srb.addFilter("matchFilter");
        srb.addThreshold(0.5);
        return srb;
    }
}
```

**PS:** You can also use [facotry method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (aka. virtual constructor) instead of a configurer.